# find the limit of (f(x) - f(-x)) /x when x goes to zero

Tags: real-analysis

Please some one help me to do the following problem.

If $f : \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is differentiable at $0$ and $f'(0) =1$, find $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(-x)}x$.

Comment: Write it as $$\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x} + \frac{f(-x) - f(0)}{-x} $$

Comment: $2f'(0)$ try to find out how.

Comment: Thanks ..But when you put -f(0) for the first part, in the second part it should be f(0) right.. Then how do we find the value of the second part.

Comment: a change of variable will do the job in the second part.

Comment: Ok, I got it. thanks a lot..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x} = f'(0)$

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(-x) - f(0)}{-x}=$$\displaystyle \lim_{y \to 0}\frac{f(y) - f(0)}{y}=f^{'}(0)$

Comment: Thank you very much. Some how I was trying this problem in many ways. I understood it well now.